# Using Nvram to Change Wifiaddr. Reverting to Original Wifiaddr

Tags: networking, ios6, jailbreak, mac-address

nvram wifiaddr=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

This is the method I used on my i5 ios6 to change my wifiaddr. Everything was smooth.

As this solution is permanent, I would like to know if there a way to revert to the original wifiaddr?

I have tried using the same method as above for recovery. However my wifiaddr is stucked with "XX:XX:XX:00:00" and it did not change to the original wifiaddr as desired no matter how many times I tried with the original address.

I have did a little research and found out that using 'nvram -d wifiaddr' may help.

Currently my phone is not jailbroken now so I have no way to test it out.

Would be helpful if anyone could enlighten me with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute 'nvram -help' in terminal you will see this

```
-d delete the named variable
```

I just did it myself and it worked. Original Wi-Fi MAC was restored. Although, I did it on my old iPhone 2G. Don't want to try anything like this on iPhone 5.

Comment: Execute `nvram -d wifiaddr` and reboot your device.